# How to uncheck menu bar option only if checked

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I am currently trying to make a script that will hide the toolbar to have the best possible fullscreen. The problem is that I can't manage to only hide the toolbar when it is necessary, so that makes it so it will show the toolbar again if it was already hidden from a previous script usage. Here is that part of the code.

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        if menu item "Hide Status Bar" of menu "View" of menu bar 1 exists then
            click menu item "Hide Status Bar" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        end if
        if menu item "Hide Favorites Bar" of menu "View" of menu bar 1 exists then
            click menu item "Hide Favorites Bar" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        end if
        if menu item "Hide Tab Bar" of menu "View" of menu bar 1 exists then
            click menu item "Hide Tab Bar" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        end if
        if menu item "Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen" of menu "View" of menu bar 1 exists then
            click menu item "Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

Can anyone help? I saw some stuff talking about actual checkboxes in system preferences but that didn't quite work...

Comment: Since the target _menu item_ exists in a normal _window_ too, albeit not enabled, I added another way to handle it as it first checks to see if it's enabled and also is checked, and if so clicks it to uncheck it. Dont forget to add another question for "I just need to find how to re-enable the toolbar when closing safari" so I can post and answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming **Safari**, per the `safari` *tag* on the question, and are only going to click the **Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen** *menu item* when it is in **Full Screen** view, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will do that.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        tell its menu "View" of menu bar 1
            if exists menu item "Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen" then
                if the value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of ¬
                    menu item "Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen" is "✓" then
                    click menu item "Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen"
                end if
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Since the target *menu item* exists in a normal *window* too, albeit not enabled, here is another way to handle it as it first checks to see if it's enabled and also is checked, and if so clicks it to uncheck it:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Safari" to ¬
        tell its menu "View" of menu bar 1 to ¬
            tell its menu item "Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen" to ¬
                if the value of attribute "AXEnabled" is true and ¬
                    the value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" is "✓" then click it
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about the fact that you couldn't compile it with the lines I provided. It works! Now I just need to find how to re-enable the toolbar when closing safari, but I have no clue how to do that; this is basically the first time I ever use Applescript. Any ideas?

Comment: @IceGod, The problem with making a change when closing **Safari** is if you've already exited **Full Screen** the **Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen** _menu item_ is not enabled. Also, triggering a _script_ when an _application_ is closing would require it being watched by another _application_ or _service_ to be able to act on it and that too can be problematic. I'll have to give it a little though, however, you'll need to ask/post that as a different question. (I actually trigger a script to change my Search Engine when I close my **VPN**, so some things can certainly be done.)

Comment: @IceGod, I have done some testing and have a method that can restore the setting **[√] Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen** when **Safari** closes. It involves using [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) to watch for **Safari** being _terminated_ and then executes a `defaults` _command_ on the target **.plist** _file_ that contains the _key_ that needs to be modified.  This does require giving **Full Disk Access** to **Hammerspoon**  in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Full Disk Access** because of the location of the target **.plist** _file_.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to do that? Or if there isn't, can you show me what you did?

Comment: @IceGod, RE: "Is there any documentation on how to do that?" --  Well there certainly is documentation at the [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) web site for installing it and its  **API** documentation some examples/brief tutorial about the **Lua** programming language, although that's only part of the picture. The `defaults` _command_ is a part of **macOS** and in **Terminal** `man defaults`  and adding to **S & P** is intuitive  -- RE: "can you show me what you did?" --  As I mentioned in my first comment "however, you'll need to ask/post that as a different question"